# Sending Email with content of a file using smtp_auth in python script

Tags: python, email

I need to send a mail using python script

```
  1 , Using smtp_auth
  2 , Mail body is file content ( may be txt or csv  )
```

anybody have an idea about this .

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the docs for `smtplib` https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example